# Gitlab CI pipeline failure

Tags: django, gitlab, cicd

My gitlab ci pipeline keeps failing. It seems am stuck here. Am actually still new to the CI thing so I don't know what am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated
Below is **.gitlab-ci.yml** file

```
image: python:latest

services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: projectdb

# This folder is cached between builds
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
  paths:
    - ~/.cache/pip/

before_script:
  - python -V

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py migrate
  only:
    - EC-30
```

The last part of the job build process say

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: What the failing job output says?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the error message

Comment: is your `python manage.py migrate` command attempting to apply postgres migrations as part of setting up django? If so, can you post at least the contents of that file where it connects to a database? It's likely that the migrations file can't connect to postgres correctly. That having been said, is there a reason you're migrating a container inside your CI/CD instead of in a development/prod environment?